# How to compare two XML files in visual studio 2010

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

How to compare two xml files in visual studio 2010? I saw some programmer compares XML files using tool but don't know which is that tool is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing two files works out of the box when your file is in team foundation server. This adds "Compare..." in the context menu. You can use blog.paulbouwer.com link above, but I would recommend James's blog, which cover almost any possible diff and merge tool
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx
The tools mentioned above winmerge and code compare do not recognize xml natively, I found stylus studio which promises xml handling http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_diff.html

Answer (score -1):

For me, WinMerge was the best I found to compare files. It can be used in Visual Studio also to compare files (source code, XML at least...).

Check it out: http://winmerge.org/

Hint to integrate it into Visual Studio (and replace the built-in diff tool): http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/

Answer (score -1):

Check this: [Code Compare](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dace3633-0b51-4629-85d4-c59cdce5bb3b)

This tool automatically integrates in VS 2010.